# Group by within View SQL server

Tags: sql-server, group-by, grouping, sql-view

Here is a view I created:

```
CREATE VIEW V_EventAnswers
AS
    SELECT ISNULL(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY e.id DESC), -1) AS RowID,
           ISNULL(Questionid, QuestionUniqueId) AS Questionid,
           QuestionUniqueId,
           QuestionNameAr,
           QuestionNameEn,
           QuestionType,
           SectionId,
           QuestionFieldOrder,
           QuestionAnswers,
           IsIssue,
           QuestionUnit,
           ReadinessIndicator,
           e.id AS EventId,
           e.SubmitionDate,
           e.Location,
           e.TenantId
    FROM EventDetails D
         CROSS APPLY
        OPENJSON(D.SubmittedJSONDATA)
            WITH (questions nvarchar(MAX) '$.fields' AS json) AS jsonValues
         OUTER APPLY
        openjson(questions)
            WITH (IsIssue bit '$.issue',
                  QuestionUnit int '$.responsibleUnit',
                  QuestionUniqueId nvarchar(100) '$.id',
                  Questionid nvarchar(100) '$.templateQuestionId',
                  QuestionNameAr nvarchar(100) '$.arLabel',
                  QuestionNameEn nvarchar(100) '$.enLabel',
                  QuestionType nvarchar(100) '$.controlType',
                  SectionId nvarchar(100) '$.sectionId',
                  QuestionFieldOrder int '$.fieldOrder',
                  ReadinessIndicator int '$.readinessIndicator',
                  answers nvarchar(MAX) '$.values' AS json) AS jsonAnswers
         OUTER APPLY
        openjson(answers)
            WITH (QuestionAnswers nvarchar(MAX) '$')
         INNER JOIN EVENT E ON E.id = D.EventId;
GO
```

I need to group the `questions` part by `'$.id'` and `EventId` to get the ``` answers``forf every ```id` in a comma separated list.

I tried too many solutions but with no output

Comment: *"I tried too many solutions but with no output"* Show us what you tried. As you're using `OPENJSON` then you have access to `STRING_AGG`, so why didn't that work?

Comment: Why use a CROSS APPLY ? You can use a natural join with OPENJSON.